# Android/IOS Library from ReactNative App parts regarding bluetooth

Tags: react-native, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

me and my team have developed a Bluetooth access control app using react native. The way it works is that our app connects to a in house hardware solution using Bluetooth 4.0+, when connected does a series of key authentifications using standard cryptography patterns.

The cryptography protocols run in a ReactNative javascript environment, and the Bluetooth connection, data transfer and service notifications are done using the [react-native-ble-manager](https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager) plugin. Authentification is done using the Bluetooth notification data received from the ble-manager plugin and the crypto javascript class.

At this moment, we have a need to implement this Bluetooth access control protocol in client applications. We would need to make a library, for both iOS and Android.

The question that I want to ask is, do we need to implement the whole app logic in native(java, swift) for both Android and iOS, or is there a solution to implement it as a ReactNative module inside native Apps.

We know that you can implement part of a native App in ReactNative, but for this specific problem how complicated it would be, and how good of a solution would it be?